# How to config Kubernetes Ingress Nginx anontations whitelist only apply to http

Tags: ssl, nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-security

I have config my ingress support SSL:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: "service"
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range: "x.x.x.x/xx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - "example.com"
    secretName: example.name
  rules:
  - host: "example.com"
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: service
          servicePort: 80
```

In my config above, only IP in whitelist can access the domain for both HTTP & HTTPS. But I would like to config all IP addresses can access `https://example.com` (HTTPS) and some IP addresses in whitelist can access without SSL - `http://example.com`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved my issue by add more config to nginx location (listen both http and https) by use `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet` annotation.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: "service"
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    # The configs to allow all IPs access via https and allow some IPs in
    # security whitelist access via http
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |

      if ($https) {
        set $allow_ip true;
      }

      if ($remote_addr ~ (x.x.x.x|y.y.y.y) {
        set $allow_ip true;
      }

      if ($allow_ip != true) {
        return 403;
      }
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - "example.com"
    secretName: example.name
  rules:
  - host: "example.com"
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: service
          servicePort: 80
```

Answer (score 0):

The `whitelist-source-range` annotation will always affect the entire Ingress resource. However, you *might* (untested!) try using two separate Ingress resources: one for HTTP access (with a source whitelist and without a `tls` configuration) and one for HTTPS (with plain HTTP disabled using the `kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http` annotation):

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: service-https
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "false"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - "example.com"
    secretName: example.name
  rules:
  - host: "example.com"
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: service
          servicePort: 80
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: service-http
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range: "x.x.x.x/xx"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: "example.com"
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: service
          servicePort: 80
```

Comment: Its only a wrapper for Nginx, right? Not familiar with the syntax but this kind of setup would work in Nginx so I don't see why it wouldn't work here.

Comment: It means 2 ingresses merged to one

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is not possible by using only nginx-ingress at the moment.
When you set up the HTTPS scheme for Ingress, it starts to listen on port 443 and [continues to listen on port 80](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce/issues/290).

However, you are able to do it by using on-premise Nginx instance as an external Load Balancer.
Follow this link for the detailed instructions: ["Kubernetes TCP load balancer service on premise (non-cloud)"](https://medium.com/@maniankara/kubernetes-tcp-load-balancer-service-on-premise-non-cloud-f85c9fd8f43c)

As another option, you may want to try [Istio Ingress](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/)